# Why do we use "-s" with verbs

Tags: grammaticality, speech

Why do we use an "s" for some verb conjugations? e.g. *I run/He run**s***. Why can't it be *I run/He run*?

Comment: Because that’s just how English works. You might as well ask why verbs have a past tense, why nouns have plural forms, why nouns are not verbs, why we use prepositions, etc. Simply because that’s an integral functional part of the English language. I’m guessing by your profile name that your first language is Arabic; so why do you conjugate verbs in masculine and feminine in Arabic? Why is there a dual? Simply because there is—that’s how the language works. It’s not possible to answer _why_ a language works in the way it does.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I am surprised by your dismissive comment. As a NNS one of the most peculiar aspect of the English language   that has always struck me  is the fact that verbs have no gender or person conjugations, apart from the 's used in the third singular person and a few other exceptions. In other languages verb coniugations are a "headache".

Comment: @Josh I don't disagree with that, but the question is too broad and unanswerable how it's currently asked. It would be perfectly on topic (but probably a duplicate) to ask how the rather odd distribution of having a specific form for the third person singular in the present but nowhere else came about—that's answerable and (somewhat) limited in scope. But that's not what the question currently is, and why English conjugates verbs according to person is an ultimately unanswerable question. As nearly always with language features, the _how_ is answerable; the _why_ is not.

Comment: More interestingly, if it is "she runs" and "he runs", why not "they runs"? Why is the personal singular the same as the plural?

Comment: I thought the question wholly reasonable, which is prolly why it got up-voted.  

Which of Janus’s examples would not change the meaning of its sentence, as third person verbs ending with *S* do not?  

I’d love someone to explain how *Why do we use an "s" for some verb conjugations? e.g. I run/He runs. Why can't it be I run/He run?* is more broad or unanswerable than *how the rather odd distribution of having a specific form for the third person singular in the present but nowhere else came about…* or how aaa90210 does more than invert the same question? Please, Janus?

Comment: I thought Janus offered a verbose paraphrase with exactly the same meaning as khalilahmed’s OQ; just less readily understandable.
Behind any of that while Josh’s Old-Middle English tale is recognisably true, it simply pushes the question back a thousand years or so.
The reason might be lost but either way *-þ, -eþ, -aþ* changing to *eth* then *s* is about pronunciation and spelling and in no way explains the glaring grammatical difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a legacy from Old English as explained in the following extract from ***[Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-origin-of-the-third-person-s-as-in-He-plays-versus-I-play):***

> - ***In Old English, certain classes of verbs were conjugated into the third person singular with the endings -þ, -eþ, -aþ (pronounced 'th', 'eth', 'ath', respectively).*** So, for example, the Old English verb 'lufian' (to love) would be conjugated 'heo lufaþ' (she loves); the verb 'werian' (to defend) would be conjugated 'he wereþ' (he defends).
> - ***In Middle English, this 'eþ'/'aþ' ending became 'eth', as in (the perhaps more familiar) 'she luveth' and 'he defendeth'***  (keep in mind that there are many, many Middle English dialects and therefore many, many different ways of actually saying 'she loves' and 'he defends' between 1066 and ~1485). ***As Middle English evolved and was used in different areas of England in the later Middle Ages, this verb ending became -***  So these verbs would have been conjugated as 'she luves' (pronounced 'shay loov-ess') and 'he defendes' (pronounced 'hay deaf-end-ess').
> - English kept on evolving, and now we are left with the 's' in third person singular conjugations!

Comment: Just a reflection but you know that Quora is a Q&A website, don't you? Wouldn't it be better to provide an original answer?

Comment: A reasonably answer with logic..Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, Janus Bahs Jacquet writes:

> Because that’s just how English works. You might as well ask why verbs have a past tense, why nouns have plural forms, why nouns are not verbs, why we use prepositions, etc. Simply because that’s an integral functional part of the English language. I’m guessing by your profile name that your first language is Arabic; so why do you conjugate verbs in masculine and feminine in Arabic? Why is there a dual? Simply because there is—that’s how the language works. It’s not possible to answer *why* a language works in the way it does.